# Azure tracing results are not uploaded

Tags: azure, trace

I am trying to get an azure role run - it runs on emulator, but not on Azure. So I tried to integrate Tracing to my project. I first tried it with a plain test project (which worked perfectly), but in my "real" project I don't get the results.

Here are my files:

app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
      <listeners>
        <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="MyServiceName" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="3" osVersion="*" schemaVersion="2013-03.2.0">
  <Role name="MyRoleName">
    <Instances count="2" />
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="StorageConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<myAccount>;AccountKey=<myKEy==>" />
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<myAccount>;AccountKey=<myKEy==>" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </Role>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

serviceDefinition.csdef

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="MyServiceName" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2013-03.2.0">
  <WorkerRole name="MyRoleName" vmsize="Small">
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
    </Imports>
    <Endpoints>
      <InternalEndpoint name="InternalEndpoint1" protocol="tcp" />
    </Endpoints>
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="StorageConnectionString" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </WorkerRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

My Source-Code (Snippet):

```
public override bool OnStart()
{

    ConfigDiagnostics();
    Trace.TraceInformation("Initializing storage account");

    // Set the maximum number of concurrent connections 
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 12;

    // For information on handling configuration changes
    // see the MSDN topic at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=166357.

    return base.OnStart();
}

private void ConfigDiagnostics()
{
    DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration config = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();
    config.ConfigurationChangePollInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1d);
    config.Logs.BufferQuotaInMB = 500;
    config.Logs.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = LogLevel.Verbose;
    config.Logs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1d);            

    //DiagnosticMonitor.Start(@"StorageConnectionString", config);
    DiagnosticMonitor.Start(@"Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString", config);
}
```

The same code works within a plain new Azure project - but not in this project. The only difference I can spot now is: My "real" project throws an exception in my run() method. Could it be that my Tracing results (from Trace.WriteLine or Trace.TraceError or Trace.TraceInformation) are not uploaded because the exception and recycling of the azure instance happens too fast / too early for uploading my tracing results to my storage account? Or is there maybe another point I missed?!

Best regards :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was another: packing an azure role with cspack and packing an azure role with Visual Studio makes a difference plus my command for packing the role in a package file was falty.

The tracing itself works perfectly the way I did above.